# How to compile Qt creator Gui application in Terminal

Tags: qt4, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a qt creator application in ubuntu terminal

/home/prabhu/backup/ToolChain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -I /home/prabhu/Downloads/iMX_For_Qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3/include main.cpp mainwindow.cpp

Is this process correct? or we need to mention mainwindow.ui

Comment: Do you have mkspec file for your target platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First we need to configure qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3  for
  the i.MX6 board type make make install Then we get a folder in file
  system Ex: opt/qt-Arm  we can found qmake file in "opt/qt-Arm/qmake"
  From qt creator we give the Tools->options->Qt4->Qt versions we give
  the qmake location manually. Then we give version name. Use our
  version name as defualt version name and compile the Qt creator
  application. Then the application compiled for iMX board.